# Using jquery How can I remove the anchor tag <a> but keep the contents?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Here is the line I'm tring to remove the  but keep the innerHTML.

`<H3 style="TEXT-ALIGN: justify" class="ms-standardheader ms-WPTitle"><A accessKey=W href="/Lists/CACSurveys"><NOBR><SPAN>My Open Surveys</SPAN><SPAN id=WebPartCaptionWPQ1></SPAN></NOBR></A></H3>`

End result should look like this:

`<H3 style="TEXT-ALIGN: justify" class="ms-standardheader ms-WPTitle"><NOBR><SPAN>My Open Surveys</SPAN><SPAN id=WebPartCaptionWPQ1></SPAN></NOBR></H3>`

Reason for this is SharePoint wont let me have web part headrs without links. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

`$('h3.ms-WPTitle > a').replaceWith(function() { return this.innerHTML; });`

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery to select the anchor tag `<a>`, and then replace its parent's contents with  its own contents. That will get rid of the anchor tag and keep everything else:

```
​$(function() {
    $('h3 a').each(function() {
        $(this).parent().html($(this).html());         
    });
});​
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/natecook/JTsKY/

Comment: I ended up using `$('h3.ms-WPTitle > a').replaceWith(function() { return this.innerHTML; });`

Answer (score 2):

Mmm... You can just use `unwrap()`:

```
$('h3 a').children().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $('.ms-WPTitle').find('span').each(function(){

     $(this).unwrap();

 });
```

hope it helps